# how to call multiple perl script from one perl script and generate the output?

Tags: xml, perl, xslt

I have written a multiple script that returns the output in xml. i have xsl file that will print out a nice table from xml for each script. however i need to write a script in which i call all those multiple scripts and create one output.?

Can this be done? if so can someone please give me an example of how this can be done.

```
  #Example Script 1

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Simple;
use Getopt::Long;

my $output = '';
my $debug = 0;
my $path;
GetOptions('path=s' => \$path,'output=s' => \$output, 'debug=i' => \$d
+ebug);

if($output eq ''){
    die ("parameter --output=s is missing");
}     
open my $xmloutput, ">", $outputFile or die "can not open $outputFile 
+";
 print $xmloutput "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<?xml-s
+tylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"book.xsl\"?>\n<Books>\n";

my $parser = new XML::Simple;
my $data = $parser->XMLin("$path");
print $xmloutput " <bookDetails> \n";
print $xmloutput "  <bookName>$data</bookName> \n";
print $xmloutput " </bookDetails> \n";
print $xmloutput " </Books> \n";
close $xmloutput;
```

Example 2

```
EXAMPLE 2
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Simple;
use Getopt::Long;

my $output = '';
my $debug = 0;
my $path;
GetOptions('path=s' => \$path,'output=s' => \$output, 'debug=i' => \$d
+ebug);

if($output eq ''){
    die ("parameter --output=s is missing");
}     
open my $xmloutput, ">", $outputFile or die "can not open $outputFile 
+";
 print $xmloutput "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<?xml-s
+tylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"Piano.xsl\"?>\n<Piano>\n";

my $parser = new XML::Simple;
my $data = $parser->XMLin("$path");
print $xmloutput " <PianoDetails> \n";
print $xmloutput "  <PianoName>$data</PianoName> \n";
print $xmloutput " </PianoDetails> \n";
print $xmloutput " </Piano> \n";
close $xmloutput;
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a controlling script that runs each of your other tools in order.

If the sub tools write their XML reformatted output to `STDOUT` you can capture it and reformat it in your controlling script using [pipe open](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html#Pipe-Opens) syntax.  If they save files, you'll need to collect up each one, massage and combine it and then cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use backticks (`).

```
my $xmlout1 = `perl xmlscript1.pl`;
my $xmlout2 = `perl xmlscript2.pl`;
my $xmlout3 = `perl xmlscript3.pl`;
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can run several perl scripts in order with [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html), no need to use the system calls. It could be done with something like this:

```
my @scripts_to_run = ('first.pl', 'second.pl', 'third.pl');
for my $script (@scripts_to_run) {
  require $script;
}
```

... although something tells me that this should be actually done with ONE script, just called with different params. ) That script could be saved as the module, included just *once* with `use` at the compile time, then called as a module method with whatever params (filenames, perhaps) you like to.

Comment: Hello Raina77ow, i have provided 2 examples. because since i am using getopt in both of the script, i am not sure how would i call both scripts in master script and print the out result. could you give me some more details please? thanks